# Does Google Cloud Platform have a preference in releasing its new features to specific locations?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does Google Cloud Platform have a preference for releasing its new features to specific locations?

Many times, Cloud service providers notify its existing customers that new services are under construction and will be released by a particular date. But these services will not be made available in all Regions. For its Beta/Alpha release usually, they choose some location.

It would be good to know, for GCP which is the preferred location for any such new release.

Answer (score 2):

By experience, us-central1 is used in all the Alpha that I used. Then, I observed that europe-west1, us-east-1 and asia-northeast-1 was the following (late alpha or early Beta)

But, it's only an observation, there is warranty on this. You can't rely on this.

Comment: This is what I observe as well. I participate in several Alpha products/services and they are all in us-central1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the product.

As [Guillaume pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286415/11480343), yes, a lot of new releases hit us-central1 first because it's one of the busiest locations but at the same time, there have been releases in europe-north1 first too as it's one of less exploited regions in GCP currently.

As far as I'm aware there is no written rule about this and it's all decided on a per-product basis, so ultimately, if you're looking forward to feature availability in your preferred region you might just want to keep an eye on the official documentation of said product.

If you want to learn more about GCP zones and regions, you can visit the [official article about the topic](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/).